# Drupal 8 - Search with decimal number and percentage sign is not working

Tags: drupal-8, elasticsearch-api

In the node, I have a title which has 66.7% number in it ,and I have enable fulltext searh in the node title, but still I am not getting any result when I search with exact number 66.7%

#### Enable search in the content type. Allow it in search API and add title,body as fulltext search. Create a search api view and create exposed filter with combine search for title and body. Add new content having number as 66.7%,and add the index from search API. When you search for any decimal number with percentage, it will show no result